# Fetching data from API but no data are being displayed in html

Tags: html, ajax, xml, api

I'm trying to fetch a specific set of data from an API as shown in the code below. Fetching only the football home teams' name and displaying it into a table.

I am getting no errors but no data is being shown in my table.

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
        {
            //document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = this.responseText;
            const obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            
             
            for (var i=0; i<obj.length; i++) 
            {
               var row = $('<tr><td>' + obj.response[i].teams.home.name + '</td></tr>');
               $('#myTable').append(row);


            }

        }
    }

    xhr.onerror = function()
    {
        console.log('Request Error');
    }

    xhr.send();
}
```

when doing console.log(obj)

[image]

Comment: It seems you have to change 'this' to 'xhr'? xhr.readyState, xhr.status, xhr.responseText

Comment: @Eddy Still no change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do [something like this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange#example)

```
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status == 200)
        {
            //document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = this.responseText;
            const obj = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            
             
            for (var i=0; i<obj.response.length; i++) 
            {
               var row = $('<tr><td>' + obj.response[i].teams.home.name + '</td></tr>');
               $('#myTable').append(row);


            }

        }
    }

    xhr.onerror = function()
    {
        console.log('Request Error');
    }

    xhr.send();
```

Comment: Eddy was correct in the comment, I have added the answer with a reference and the improved code

Comment: I tried both your code and the code from the referenced website but still no change. I created a json file with random data and tried fetching from the json file just to see whether the code was working but still getting the same problem

Comment: Did you try logging parse reponse `console.log(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText))`? what is the output for this

Comment: Also you could `console.log(xhr.status)` outside the if condition, so you could see response of the request

Comment: i added a picture of what console.log gives me

Comment: `console.log(xhr.status)` returns 200

Comment: updated the answer, you have to change the for loop to `for (var i=0; i<obj.response.length; i++)` since you are printing something in the response array. BTW this the problem with processing the response.